# How to compare results to a reference with multiple measurements

Tags: standard-error, distance-functions, chemometrics

I have run a pilot test in the laboratory to see which method is best out of 5 different ones. I have reference numbers for a range of measurements to compare these against and then my results for the same measurements. What test should I run to identify which method is the best across all measurements? Or should I run a different test for each measurement and then run standard error across them?

Detail:
Sediment tested for concentration of 3 heavy metals.
5 different methods for testing have been carried out, all of them on sediment which I know the heavy metal concentration for.
Results for all 5 methods now need to be compared to my 'reference' concentrations.
For example: the reference concentrations are: copper=2; zinc=3; cadmium=4. 5 different methods (each with 6 results) have given me a range of results around these numbers. I now need to statistically prove which method gives the result that is closest overall to the reference numbers.